# Como añadir elementos a un string dentro de un hashmap individualmente?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Estoy tratando de hacer un diccionario en el que se añaden definiciones diferentes a una misma palabra como por ejemplo, tierra, que tiene diferentes definiciones, pero tambien necesito añadir una segunda palabra que es fuego pero a la hora de añadir las definiciones se le añaden a las dos palabras. Pongo aqui mi codigo( el problema es con el metodo agregarAcepcion pero pongo lo demas por si acaso:

```
public Diccionario()
    {
        diccionario = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void agregarPalabra(String palabra, ArrayList<String> acepciones)
    {
        diccionario.put(palabra,acepciones);
    }

    public void imprimir()
    {
        TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> diccionarioOrdenado = new TreeMap<>();
        diccionarioOrdenado.putAll(this.diccionario);
        for (var entrada : diccionarioOrdenado.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entrada.getKey());
            ArrayList<String> acepciones = entrada.getValue();
            for (int i = 1; i <= acepciones.size(); i++) {
                String acepcion = acepciones.get(i-1);
                System.out.println(i + ". " + acepcion);
            }
        }
    }

    public void imprimirDefinicion(String palabra)
    {
        System.out.println(palabra);
        for (String d : diccionario.get(palabra)){
            System.out.println(d.toString());
        }
    }

    public void agregarAcepcion(String palabra, String acepcion)
    {
        if (diccionario.get(palabra) == null) { 
            diccionario.put(palabra, new ArrayList<String>()); 
            diccionario.get(palabra).add(acepcion);
        }
        else{
            diccionario.get(palabra).add(acepcion);
        }
    }
```

Lo que tira la consola es esto:

```
Tierra
Planeta que habitamos.
Superficie del planeta Tierra.
Material desmenuzable de que principalmente se compone el suelo natural
Fuego
Planeta que habitamos.
Superficie del planeta Tierra.
Material desmenuzable de que principalmente se compone el suelo natural
Fenómeno caracterizado por la emisión de calor y de luz, generalmente con llama.
```

Cuando debería tirar:

```
Tierra.
Planeta que habitamos.
Superficie del planeta Tierra.
Material desmenuzable de que principalmente se compone el suelo natural.
Fuego.
Fenómeno caracterizado por la emisión de calor y de luz, generalmente con llama.
```

Ayuda, por favor:(

Comment: ¿Puedes cargar todo el código?

Comment: hola Mateo:) ahi actualicé y puse todo el codigo, gracias por querer ayudar! puse mas codigo demas pero el problema es con el metodo agregarAcepcion

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que hay algún problema? Acabo de probarlo y funciona bien. Mira: https://ideone.com/NpT2Qn

Comment: que extraño… y si lo pruebas con el método imprimir definición?

Comment: Tampoco. Compara los códigos y averigua qué es lo que funciona mal así te podemos ayudar.

Comment: hola, llevo analizando el codigo un rato y no logro encontrar cual era el error, pero ahora si sirve, muy extraño, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Me imagino que lo arreglaste tu solo entre el momento en que publicaste la pregunta y la editaste. Por cierto, en la función `agregarAcepcion`, como `diccionario.get(palabra).add(acepcion)` aparece en ambos casos puedes sacarlo después del condicional y te quedaría un `else` vacío que puedes quitar.